# How do I read CURL PUT data using PHP?

Tags: php, curl

How do I read the data sent using CURL PUT in PHP? I have POST and GET working but PUT does not work. I have found out that you have to read the data using `php://input`. How do I parse the data?

Here is the PUT file test15.php:

```
<?php
// CURL PUT Test

$browser     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$url  = 'http://localhost/curltest/test15_put.php';  
// echo "URL: $url <br>";

$headers = array( 
  "Accept: application/json" 
); 

// set post fields
$post = array(
    'firstname'  => 'John',
    'lastname'   => 'Doe',
    'email'      => 'email@domain.com',
    'notes'      => 'Test user to test CURL PUT request'
    );
$post2 = json_encode($post);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Here is the receiving file test15_put.php:

```
<?php
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post_vars);

$firstname  = $post_vars['firstname'];
$lastname   = $post_vars['lastname'];

$value = array('firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname);
echo json_encode($value);
?>
```

This is the data I get out:

```
Array
(
    [--------------------------f7bdbb5224ed4e09
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "firstname"

John
--------------------------f7bdbb5224ed4e09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname"

Doe
--------------------------f7bdbb5224ed4e09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

email@domain.com
--------------------------f7bdbb5224ed4e09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="notes"

Test user to test CURL PUT request
--------------------------f7bdbb5224ed4e09--

)
```

Is there another method to send the data and receive a better response?

**UPDATE** 2016-11-29
Here is the returned $GLOBALS data:

```
 [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
  [browser] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
  [url] => http://localhost/milk/test15_put.php
  [headers] => Array
      (
          [0] => Accept: application/json
      )

  [post] => Array
      (
          [firstname] => John
          [lastname] => Doe
          [email] => email@domain.com
          [notes] => Test user to test CURL PUT request
      )

  [post2] => {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","email":"email@domain.com","notes":"Test user to test CURL PUT request"}
  [curl] => Resource id #2
  [response] =>
```

**Update 3** - 2016-12-08

I tried to use the code from *S.Pinkus*. I use a Windows PC running XAMPP with PHP 5.6.21. I'm still getting empty arrays returned and not the values I need. I also code my PHP and run from a browser, not the command line. Here is my modified code of *S.Pinkus* and the output:

```
<?php
// CURL PUT Test

$browser     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$url  = 'http://localhost/curltesting/test16_put.php';  
// echo "URL: $url <br>";

$payload = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
// PUT JSON. \$_POST is not set server side. php://input gives the JSON payload.
print "<br>### TEST 1 (application/json):<br>";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);

// PUT form data. \$_POST is set by PHP server side.\n";
echo "<br>### TEST 2 (multipart/form-data):<br>";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);

?>
```

Here is test16_put.php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
echo "\n### \$_POST: <br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre><br>";
echo "<br><br>### Request Body: <br>";
echo file_get_contents('php://input') . "<br>";

?>
```

This is the output I get:

```
### TEST 1 (application/json):
string(89) " ### $_POST: 
Array
(
)

### Request Body: 
{"x":1,"y":2}
" 
### TEST 2 (multipart/form-data):
string(304) " ### $_POST: 
Array
(
)

### Request Body: 
--------------------------8f21ab28aa12c814 Content-Disposition: 
form-data; name="x" 1 --------------------------8f21ab28aa12c814 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="y" 2 
--------------------------8f21ab28aa12c814-- 
"
```

It seems like I only get the required data returned in the Request Body string and no where else...

Comment: Do you have some variables in $GLOBALS or $_REQUEST in test15_put.php ?

Comment: I found something in $GLOBALS. Is this safe to use? Is this the normal way to read a CURL PUT request?

Comment: You don't need GLOBALS. It's not the normal way to read a CURL PUT request! Also it's not clear whether your trying to send post data or JSON. Specifically the variable $post2 with JSON in it is defined but never used.

Comment: $post gives the array data and $post2 gives the JSON data. By changing the variable I tried to test both ways. Still no luck in extracting the information I need...

Answer (score 2):

To the question *"How do read data sent with a HTTP PUT request in PHP"*, the answer is, there are two (normal) ways. Which way you use depends on how you send the data - specifically what `Content-Type` you send:

If you use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` with an **array**, Curl will send a request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. PHP will recognize this `Content-Type` and parse the body into the [$_POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal array (whether it's a PUT or POST request). Once PHP has done this parsing you won't be able to retrieve the content of the body via `php://input` [anymore](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) - I'm not entirely sure why that is, but since it's in $_POST there is little reason to want to.

But if you just want to send an arbitrary body (like say JSON or TXT or XML ...) put the data in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as a string (you can also put a reference to a file in there but that is beyond scope of the question), and set the `Content-Type` appropriately. PHP **won't** populate `$_POST`, and the way you read the data is with `php://input`

**UPDATE: Example:**

(Aside: by doing the following tests I discovered PHP (5.6 anyway) **will** parse an `application/json` payload into $_POST. But in this case it still leaves `php://stdin` so you can retrieve a JSON payload via either method. This would have to be a convenience limited to `application/json` payloads though because other payloads don't have an obvious expansion into an array...).

Here is a test client (*curl-put-debug-script.php*):

```
<?php
isset($argv[1]) or die("Usage: {$argv[0]} <URL>\n");
$payload = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
// PUT JSON. \$_POST is not set server side. php://input gives the JSON payload.
print "\n### TEST 1 (application/json):\n";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $argv[1]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);

// PUT form data. \$_POST is set by PHP server side.\n";
print "\n### TEST 2 (multipart/form-data):\n";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $argv[1]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

Here's a simple test end point you can hit up for debug (*curl-debug-svr.php*):

```
<?php
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
print "\n### \$_POST:\n";
print_r($_POST);
print "### Request Body:\n";
print file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n";
```

Now, running the server, and hitting it up with the test script like this - assuming you have both scripts in the current working directory:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 2>/dev/null &
php curl-put-debug-script.php "http://127.0.0.1:8000/curl-debug-svr.php"
```

Gives the following:

```
### TEST 1 (JSON):
string(81) "
### $_POST:
Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [y] => 2
)
### Request Body:
{"x":1,"y":2}
"

### TEST 2 (multipart/form-data):
string(68) "
### $_POST:
Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [y] => 2
)
### Request Body:

"
```

This shows that `php://stdin` returns nothing for multipart/form-data (I.e. when you give `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` an array).

---

**UPDATE: Addressing Your Code Example**

In brief:

1. I'm not sure why you are setting `Accept: application/json` header. That has no effect in this case. If your sending JSON you want to set `Content-Type: application/json`. But you are not sending JSON in your example.
2. As it is listed you are passing your server form data (because of this line `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`). When doing this you have to read the data from `$_POST` super global. You **can't** (or at least [your not supposed](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)) read it from `stdin://input`.
3. The messed up "output" data you show looks like `$post_var` on server side. About right for trying to `parse_str()` a multipart/form-data encoded body. But I'm not sure why `std://input` is returning anything. Makes me wonder what PHP version your using.

Comment: I tried the above. The first code gives me a summary, but most of the data is an array. How do I view those arrays as you loop through the data? The only place I can see the data is in the Request Body, but I still can not get the individual items I am trying to read

Comment: @andrebruton I've tried to make the example a bit easier to follow for you, and revised the answer along the way. Hope this helps.